# weighted multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, weighted-regression

I need to do a weighted multiple linear regression. If I want to weigh certain observations differently, am I correct that I simply have to multiply the y(i) of that observation, and the corresponding row in X, with that weight?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The way to do it is to multiply every X value, every y value *and the constant* by $\sqrt{w_i}$.

So $x_{ij}^* = \sqrt{w_i}x_{ij}$

$x_{i0}^* = \sqrt{w_i}.1$

$y_{i}^* = \sqrt{w_i}y_{i}$

And then do that regression of $y^*$ on $X^*$ (only you don't have a constant column now, since the coefficient of $x_{i0}$ does that job).

Alternatively, you use a package or program that does weighted regression for you.

Comment: If I never had a constant because I'm not using OLS but some other regression technique, does everything stay the same except that I don't multiply the constant because there is none?

Comment: @JeffG. you'll get a better answer if you explain exactly what you're doing, including at a minimum what the "other regression technique" is.

Comment: Can you use the same technique for weighting when you do higher-polynomial regression (using SVD)? I.e just multiply X,Y, and bias vector by the square root of weights and do the same calculation as otherwise.